# can't find reduceByKey method on spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using spark-core_2.10 jar on my Java eclipse. I can't find any reduceBykey method in that! All i get as suggestion for `reduce` are `reduce` and `treeReduce`. Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: What does your RDD look like? Does it contain a tuple? Or a single value, i.e. `RDD[String]`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov actually it was JavaRDD<Tuple2<String,Integer>>. Never mind found it works only with PairRDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java there is more hassle with `PairRDD` (compared to Scala, where the types are automatically inferred, or Python that doesn't consider types and *expects* tuples in runtime). As `reduceByKey` needs to know the key, it is [defined on `JavaPairRDD`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#reduceByKey(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2)) class.

You can get `JavaPairRDD` from *normal* `RDD` by calling [`JavaRDD#mapToPair`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#mapToPair(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction)). You provide `PairFunction` that returns tuple where the first element is taken as a key in the resulting `JavaPairRDD`.

Answer (score 2):

`reduceByKey` works only on RDD where there are key-value like data, they are called pairRDD.

Adding to the answers above, it doesn't matter if you work on Scala of Java, as long as your dataset is correct.

The `ReduceByKey` will work on Tuple data in the following manner.

```
val l1 = List((1,2), (1,3), (4,2))
val l1RDD = sc.parallelize(l1)
l1RDD.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

ouput is:
(1,5)
(4,2)

Answer (score 0):

Post you code and you RDD details `reduceByKey` is part of PairRDD .if you have created the PairRDD then you can see the `reduceByKey`.